# Jira Xray copy / push steps of a testcase to git (bitbucket)

Tags: test-management, jira, git

I would like to commit / push all test steps of a [jira-xray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jira-xray) issue into git without writing custom code for the provided [XRAY REST API](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAY/v1.0)s.

The workflow should be something like this

- Each day all jira issues of type test that were updated are filtered like this `project = <YOUR-PROJECT-KEY> and type = test and updatedDate > startOfDay()`
- for each issue in this filter result all test steps are exported as csv into git / bitbucket (optional the attached / associated images as well)

Do you know a plugin / extension or an easy way (configuration, external tool, open source library) that can copy / check in all steps into [jira bitucket](https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/bitbucket-integration)?

### Images for illustration

##### Filtered Jira issues

[image: Jira Issues filtered]

##### Test Steps for a test

[image: Jira Test Steps of an issues]